# Getting error running hostnames cookbook - Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Not sure why but when I try to reference the hostnames cook book I get an error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
```

My wrapper cookbook only has include_recipe "hostanmes" in it and the cookbook is located on disk in the cookbooks directory. I do not have this issue with any of my other cookbooks so I think there is something strange going on here.

I'm using this recipe:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/hostnames

Any ideas why I would be getting this error? I'm running this recipe from Test Kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

Add `depends 'hostname'` to the metadata.rb for your wrapper cookbook.

Comment: I was hoping it would be that easy but that does not work. I can edit the hostnames cookbook and add it to the run list and it works but it does not seem to want to work in a wrapper cookbook....

Comment: Basically you need to make sure the cookbook is transferred to the test host. If you have a `Berksfile` with a `metadata` line in it, then adding things to the metadata is enough. If you are no using Berks, then you might need something more complex.

Comment: I stuck it in a Policyfile :) adding hostnames to the runlist works but using include_recipe 'hostnames' in the main app cookbook I'm creating fails. Also, trying to add a policy_group specific hostname via something like node[Chef::Config.polc_group]['set_fqdn'] does not seem to work... (both other policy_group specific things I set do... for instance node[Chef::Config.policy_group]['efs']['database_mount']

Comment: Are you using poise-hoist?

Comment: No... have not had a change to figure out how to use that yet.

Comment: Then the group-level attributes won't work automatically unless the cookbook is specifically written for it.

Comment: Looking at your tutorial on policyfiles it looks like all i need using poise-hoist in the hostnames cookbook attributes defualt.rb would be default.update(default[node.policy_group]) and then define something like default['local'][set_fqdn] = '*.local' ? Because this did not seem to work... I could have screwed up the syntax somewhere however....

Comment: It sounds like you need more detailed help on using Policyfiles, I would jump on the Chef community Slack team and ask there.

Comment: Not sure what is going on with this cookbook or but I've used hostnames in several policyfile based cookbooks after this one and it works without issues... I need to go back and rework this cookbook!